# Magento 2.2.5: Add, Update and Delete existing products Custom Options

Tags: magento2, admin, custom-options, magento-2.2.5, programmatically

I am working on updating custom options of an existing product programatically when admin click product save button -

I have done below code to full fil my desire -

```
app/code/Namespace/Module/etc/adminhtml/events.xml
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

    <!-- Admin Product Before save -->
    <event name="catalog_product_save_before">
        <observer name="catalogProductSaveBefore" instance="Namespace\Module\Observer\Admin\catalogProductSaveBefore" />
    </event>
</config>
```

```
app/code/Namespace/Module/Observer/Admin/catalogProductSaveBefore.php
```

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Observer\Admin;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CatalogProductSaveBefore implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $productRepository;

    protected $productCustomOptionInterface;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface $productCustomOptionInterface
    ){
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->productCustomOptionInterface = $productCustomOptionInterface;
    }   

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();     
        if($product->getSubscriptionDisplayCalendar()){
            $found=0; //0 if Custom Option not Found
            if($product->getOptions()){
                foreach ($product->getOptions() as $opt){
                    if($opt->getTitle()=='Delivery'){
                        $found=1; // if Custom Option Found
                        break;
                    }                   
                }               
            }

            if(!$found){ //if Not Found then create a new one
                $customOptions = array();
                //Add New Custom Option not already exists
                $this->productCustomOptionInterface->setTitle('Delivery')
                                                ->setType('date')
                                                ->setIsRequire(true)
                                                ->setSortOrder(1)
                                                ->setPrice(0.00)
                                                ->setPriceType('fixed')
                                                ->setMaxCharacters(50)
                                                ->setProductSku('');

                $customOptions[] = $this->productCustomOptionInterface;
                $product->setOptions($customOptions);
            }

        } else {
            if($product->getOptions()){
                foreach ($product->getOptions() as $opt){                   
                    if($opt->getTitle()=='First Delivery'){
                        $opt->unsetOptions();                                           
                        break;
                    }                   
                }               
            }
        }       
    }   
}
```

The above code should work , but its showing error, I also try to save product here but it hangs system.

Anyone has gone through like above condition?
Still looking for update.